# Using INDIRECT function in sheet name in IMPORTRANGE function

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, importrange

I want to create a Resource Planning spreadsheet, which imports data from a Monthly Planning spreadsheet using Google Sheets. The Monthly Planning spreadsheet has one sheet per month, named 'Oct 2013', 'Nov 2013', etc. In the Resource Planning spreadsheet I would like to always import the current month using Google Sheet's IMPORTRANGE function:

```
=TEXT(NOW(),"MMM yyyy")
```

The formula above would give me the current month / year in the format, which is also used for the sheet names in the Monthly Planning, e.g. 'Oct 2013'

```
=ImportRange("UniqueKey",INDIRECT(TEXT(NOW(),"MMM yyyy")&"!SheetRange"))
```

The IMPORTRANGE function just gives me a `#REF!` error though. Tested directly in the Monthly Planning sheet I can call the content of another cell with:

```
=INDIRECT(TEXT(NOW(),"MMM yyyy")&"!SheetRange"
```

though, hence either the IMPORTRANGE function does not like the INDIRECT function or I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really need to use INDIRECT? I think the formula shown below, should do what you need:

```
=ImportRange("UniqueKey"; TEXT(NOW(),"MMM yyyy")&"!SheetRange")
```

Comment: I think the formula shown below, should do what you need

Yes, your shorter version actually did the trick. Damn overcomplication – I think I went full retard on that one.

Thanks for your quick help wchiquito! :)